# Mapping a value into a specific column based on annother column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the following problem:

- A `DataFrame` containing `col1` with strings `A`, `B`, or `C`.
- A second `col2` with an `Integer`.
- And three other columns `col3`, `col4` and `col5` (these columns are also named `A`, `B`, and `C`).

Thus,

```
 col1 - col2 - A (col3) - B (col4) - C (col5)
|--------------------------------------------
   A      6
   B      5
   C      6
```

should obtain

```
 col1 - col2 - A (col3) - B (col4) - C (col5)
|--------------------------------------------
   A      6       6
   B      5                  5
   C      6                              6
```

Now I would like to go through each row and assign the integer in `col2` to the column A, B or C based on the entry in `col1`.

How do I achieve this?

`df.withColumn()` I cannot use (or at least I do not know why) and the same holds for `val df2 = df.map(x => x )`.

Looking forward to you help and thanks in advance!

Best, Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping between key and target column:

```
val mapping = Seq(("A", "col3"), ("B", "col4"), ("C", "col5"))
```

Use it to generate sequence of columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

val exprs = mapping.map { case (key, target) => 
  when($"col1" === key, $"col2").alias(target) }
```

Prepend star and select:

```
val df = Seq(("A", 6), ("B", 5), ("C", 6)).toDF("col1", "col2")
df.select($"*" +: exprs: _*)
```

The result is:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   A|   6|   6|null|null|
|   B|   5|null|   5|null|
|   C|   6|null|null|   6|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```